# Why does fluent nhibernate not cache results if using an IEnumerable instead of a List

Tags: c#, performance, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Edit: Changed my test around as there was a flaw with the way the test was being run.

I was fighting some performance issues with Fluent Nhibernate recently and I came across something I thought was very odd. When I made an IEnumerable a List performance increased dramatically. I was trying to figure out why. It didn't seem like it should, and google didn't turn anything up.

Here's the basic test I ran:

```
//Class has various built in type fields, but no references to anything
public class Something
{
  public int ID;
  public decimal Value;
}

var someRepository = new Repository(uow);

//RUN 1
var start = DateTime.Now;
// Returns a IEnumerable from a session.Linq<SomeAgg> based on the passed in parameters, nothing fancy. Has about 1300 rows that get returned.
var somethings = someRepository.GetABunchOfSomething(various, parameters);
var returnValue = SumAllFunction(somethings);
var timeSpent = DateTime.Now - start; //Takes {00:00:00.3580358} on my box

//RUN2
var start2 = DateTime.Now;
var returnValue = someFunction(somethings);
var timeSpent = DateTime.Now - start2; //Takes {00:00:00.0560000} on my box



public decimal SumAllFunction(IEnumerable<Something> somethings)
{
  return somethings.Sum(x => x.Value); //Value is a decimal that's part of the Something class
}
```

Now if I take the same code and just change the line someRepository.GetABunchOfSomethingto and appened .ToList():

```
//RUN 1
var start = DateTime.Now;
var somethings = someRepository.GetABunchOfSomething(various, parameters).ToList(); 
var returnValue = SumAllFunction(somethings);
var timeSpent = DateTime.Now - start; //Takes {00:00:00.3580358} on my box

//RUN 2
var start2 = DateTime.Now;
var returnValue = SumAllFunction(somethings);
var timeSpent = DateTime.Now - start2; //Takes {00:00:00.0010000} on my box
```

Nothing else changed. These results are very repeatable. So it's not just a one off timing issue.

**The TLDR version is this:**

When running the same IEnumerable through a loop twice the second run takes anywhere from 10-20 time longer than if I change the IEnumerable to a List using .ToList() before running it through the 2 loops.

I checked the SQL and when it's a List then the sql only gets run once and appears to be cached and used again rather than having to go back to the database to get the results.

If it's an IEnumerable then everytime it goes to access the children of the IEnumerable it makes a trip to the database to rehydrate them.

I understand that you can't add to/delete from an IEnumerable, but my understanding was that the IEnumerable would have been initially filled with the proxy objects and then the proxy objects would have been hydrated later on when needed. After they were hydrated you wouldn't have to go back to the DB again, but it does not appear to be that way. I obviously have a work around for this, but I thought it was odd and I was curious why it behaves the way it does.

Comment: Could you profile sql statements that get executed?

Comment: What does `someFunction` do? Could you show its code? (Do you think it is easy to compare your two codes? Don't you think it would be easier to understand if you had written "if I replace that line with....")

Comment: @L.B. someFunction is shown, it's the last 3 lines of the code. I changed the 2nd code block around to better show what changed. 
empi: I'll try to get a Sql profile and update the question.

Comment: the most precise answer would be to build + decompile and see what's up.  its *probably* because of what your someFunction is doign against an ienumerable/iqueryable.  It might turn into multiple db round trips, where the toList makes one bulk retrieval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `ToList()` on your `GetABunchOfSomething` result, the query is performed at that moment, and the results are placed in a list.  When you don't call `ToList()`, then it's not until `someFunction` runs that the query is performed, and your timer doesn't take that into account.

I think you'll find that the time difference between the two are due to that.

**Update**

The results, though maybe counter-intuitive to you, makes sense.  The reason why the query isn't run until you iterate, and the reason why the results aren't cached, is provided as a feature.  Say you wanted to call your repository method in two places in your code; one time sorted by `Foo`, another time filtered by `Bar`.  If the repository method returns an `IQueryable<YourClass>`, any additional modifications made to that object will actually affect the SQL that gets emitted rather than causing the collection to be modified in-memory.  For example, if you ran this:

```
someRepository
    .GetABunchOfSomething(various, parameters)
    .Where(s => s.Bar == "SomeValue");
```

The generated SQL might look something like this once you iterate:

```
select *
from someTable
where Bar = 'SomeValue'
```

However, if you did this instead:

```
someRepository
    .GetABunchOfSomething(various, parameters)
    .ToList()
    .Where(s => s.Bar == "SomeValue");
```

Then you'll be retrieving all rows from the table instead, and your application would filter the results.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the flaw, there is still an underlying issue but once I fixed my test I was at least able to get better data and show the difference correctly.

Comment: Ahh Ok that makes much more sense. Thank you very much.